# Как запретить ComboBox принимать значение null?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Пользователь выбирает значение в первом `ComboBox`, содержащим значения из базы данных.
Далее, в зависимости от выбранного значения в первом `ComboBox`, должны появляться значения во втором ComboBox.
То есть, второе значение связано с первым в базе данных.

```cs
string selectTitle = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); //получение данных из ComboBox1
```

Но появляются ошибки:

> Разыменование пустой ссылки

> Преобразование литерала, допускающего значение NULL, в тип не допускающий значения NULL.

Работаю с EF.

Comment: Сам ComboBox такое делать не умеет, т.е. для фильтрации вы должны написать дополнительный код

Comment: какой именно код?

Comment: На подобные вопросы у меня есть традиционный ответ: ошибка в строке 123. | Вы всерьёз полагаете, что мы, не видя ваш код, сможем чем-то помочь? Экстрасенсы, как всегда, в отпуске.

Answer (score 1):

Почему `SelectedValue` возвращает `null`? Скорее всего, вы не установили свойство `ComboBox.ValueMember`. Или установите пару `DisplayMember/ValueMember`, или используйте `ComboBox.Text`. Ну, и проверка на `null` не помешает:

```
string? selectTitle = comboBox1.SelectedValue?.ToString();
```

Пусть у вас есть набор `tmp`, который возвращает, как минимум, объект из двух строк:

```
var tmp = dbcontext.dbset.Where(кстати, тут можно вставить w => w.String1 != null).Select(s => new { s.String1, s.String2 } );
```

Первый комбобокс вы заполняете первым полем:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = tmp.Select(s => new { s.String1 } ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Второй комбобокс вы запоняете вторым полем:

```
void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ComboBox2.DataSource = tmp.Where(w => w.String1 == ComboBox1.Text).Select(s => new { s.String2 } ).ToList();
}
```

Сделайте форму с одним комбобоксом (или двумя) и поизучайте, как он работает. Это будет проще, чем делать отладку в большом приложении.